# Deny Creating Public Buckets / Objects in GCP Buckets

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Is it possible to create a policy in GCP that will disallow the creation of public buckets or items in buckets?

If yes, how that policy will look like?

Answer (score 1):

Storage Object Admin or Storage Admin [roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#cloud_storage_roles) are needed for [making data public](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public). If you exclude these roles from an account and add Storage Object Creator or Storage Object Viewer roles, depending on your use-case, the account will not be able to make data public but create or copy objects.